# When does the Steam discovery queue card availability reset?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I am hoping to capitalize on obtaining as many trading cards as possible before they expire on July 4th. Is the gap between earning cards from the discovery queue based on a specific global reset time, or must a certain amount of time pass before I can earn cards again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's 10 AM Pacific time (note that at the moment, the Pacific time zone is observing Daylight Saving time). In the past, that's when the new sales begin.